# CORS with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cors

I am writing an API, and using Laravel 4 to achieve that. My api is at a different domain. lets assume that it is: `http://api-example.com/`

And when i try to make ajax requests via Backbone to my api from my web-app (i.e `mydomain.com`) with basic authentication, it sometimes works just fine, but sometimes it doesn't. I am trying to figure out why. Below are my `App::before` filter and `App::after` filter.

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
        $statusCode = 204;

        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => 'http://mydomain.com',
            'Allow'                            => 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true'
        ];

        return Response::make(null, $statusCode, $headers);
    }
});
```

And my after filter:

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://mydomain.com');
    $response->headers->set('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    return $response;
});
```

The thing is when i try to make a post request to `/login` with the credentials, API checks the db and gets the API key for the user. This is just working fine. But when i try to make a POST request to `/users` chrome just gives me following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api-example.com/users. Origin http://mydomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I tried everything, such as setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `'*'` everything i could be able to find from internet. But nothing worked so far. I don't know what i should do.

Comment: Inspecting the network with something like Chrome Dev Tools shows that it's there or not there (the header)?

Comment: Any non-GET operation first does an OPTIONS "pre-flight" request - as it looks like you know. Ensure that your before filter is run even when no route exists to match it. Also, are you attempting PUT or DELETE requests? Your headers don't allow those. Finally, origin '*' can't be used with authorization. Actually, last note: what's your Ajax request look like? jQuery has a setting for sending requests with authorization.

Comment: I don't think that headers are set. Instead of `$response->headers->set()` try `header('Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS')` might work

Comment: Actually, it turns out, this code is all fine, instead, i had an other problem in other place. And also, i guess it was because the Resourceful routes. When i change it to its own route, it started to work. Anyways guys, thank you for all of the comments.

Comment: Consider using Stack-Cors, some middleware from the stackphp.com creators - https://github.com/asm89/stack-cors. They're libs works with any Symfony request/response stuff, which Laravel uses.

Answer (score 6):

There is a mistake in the header name.

```
header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS'); // This is wrong.

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS'); // This is right.
```

Comment: This is the actual mistake. I am doing same thing with correct RESPONSE and it is working fine with me. @umut-sirin

Answer (score 3):

There is no point making a fancy response object and returning it, then letting the page process run as it'll obliterate your CORS headers and continue with the usual content.

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {

        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://mydomain.com');
        header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

        exit;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers may deny this, because XSS scripts are doing nasty things in that way.

If you load your js file from http://api-example.com/ might help, but there are more stable solutions:

- You can use curl (or something similar) or
- You can use a proxy (Apache, Nginx, etc) for your AJAX request to load the response from the other host
- Or if you are useing a load balancer, or frontend cacheing stuff, you can create a rule...

It depends on your infrastructure and needs, but if performance matters, skip curl.

Comment: I am sorry, but i am really newbie about the load balancer stuff, can you explain in detail, if it is OK for you? Because i am using Amazon ELB for load balancer, and i don't know the meaning of 'creating a rule'.